# How to hide the grid lines from Yaxis and draw only one line from specific Yaxis points?

Tags: 7, charts

I am creating a view using the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module. I am using the (interactive) [Google Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery) as the charting engine.

Is it possible to hide other gridlines and only display one grid line from a specific y axis point?

Just like in this image:

[image]

Comment: You could do this with chart_definition_alter function. See the question and answer about **charts module settings per chart** (with views integration): http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/137737/charts-module-settings-per-chart-with-views-integration

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [HowTos about vertical axis](https://www.drupal.org/node/2443385), located within the [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/233753) of the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module. Here is the relevant part of it:

> Refer to [#2356053-2: Automatically adjusted value range for vertical axis](https://www.drupal.org/comment/9254747#comment-9254747), which explains how to automatically adjust the minimum and maximum of the Y-axis to fit the available data. Specifying a "Max" and "Min" value is optional. Specifying a minimum of 0 is recommended in the event that numbers will always be positive, while for the maximum value the recommendation is (usually) to just leave it empty.
>
> To experiment with this in your own site, use the column chart with the number of nodes for each content type (located in charts/examples/views ):
>
> - If you do not specify a maximum there, you get a close to perfect chart, no?
> - If however you only have a few nodes (like a dozen or so) but use a huge maximum (like 240 ...), the chart looks not so nice, right?

Comment: Any feedback on this?